# git - Master builds ok, but taking a clean branch from master fails the build

Tags: git

I'm using git and I have a remote repo with `master` branch. This branch currently builds perfectly on my local machine and our remote Jenkins server and all tests pass 100%...this has been verified by all my colleagues.

If I take a local branch of `master`, make no changes and push my new branch to the remote server.

The build machine builds this new branch and even though I made no changes it fails. Usually 10-1000 unit tests fail.

I seems I am the only person in my company (100+ employees) this happens for.

I've triple checked...this is no difference between remote master and my local branch.

When I compare the revision of the remote master and remote branch they are identical, yet no passes and one fails...!!

The build continues to fail as I make commits to my local branch and push to remote.

After this first build fail, every time I branch from master and make no changes (i.e. the branch is still on the same revision as remote master) the build will fail...so that feels like git on the build server is somehow caching the instance, rather than creating a clean copy.

Strangley...if I now create a new local branch from master, cherry-pick my local commits and push it all to remote, the build will mostly likely start passing now...as long as the revision does not match the original build version which failed.

This make no sense at all...any ideas?!

Comment: Does the build process or test runner depend on the branch name somehow?

Comment: I don't believe so and its only unit tests that fail, which should not be affected by the branch name at all